# Why does `git range-diff` not show the difference I expect?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have next output for `git range-diff`

[image]

I see that `8fa7b780` commit in history is changed by `3272627a` but nothing else is displayed. What do those two first lines (red/green) mean?

```
$ git range-diff 11f75961...1c1e98db
1:  8fa7b780 < -:  -------- Add Test: interval_match.t
-:  -------- > 1:  3272627a Add Test: interval_match.t
2:  bb4bd0ca = 2:  73b5794b Allow to force current month
3:  9e2f487b = 3:  ea8c2570 Saldo anal table now does not requires extra processing
4:  ddd3362f = 4:  6a82658a Prettify code
5:  b444b0c7 = 5:  2896bf63 Add check for deactivated agreements/contractors
6:  7464d470 = 6:  f2eac3de Install required modules to pars XLS files
7:  11f75961 = 7:  1c1e98db Allow to upload saldo via web interface
```

If I compare commits `8fa7b780` and `3272627a` I see the changes:

```
interdiff -w -b -B <(git show 8fa7b780) <(git show 3272627a)
diff -wbBu b/t/MaitreD/interval_match.t b/t/MaitreD/interval_match.t
--- b/t/MaitreD/interval_match.t
+++ b/t/MaitreD/interval_match.t
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@
 my $db =  $t->app->db;
 
 
-sub match {
+sub query {
    my $qr_im =  <<"    SQL";
        select * from interval_match( $_[0], $_[1], '$_[2]' )
    SQL
```

but `range-diff` does not show them. Did I miss something?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.24.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can use `--creation-factor` parameter.

> ```
>   --creation-factor=<percent>
>       Set the creation/deletion cost fudge factor to <percent>. Defaults to 60.
>       Try a larger value if git range-diff erroneously considers a large change a
>       total rewrite (deletion of one commit and addition of another), and a
>       smaller one in the reverse case. See the ``Algorithm`` section below for an
>       explanation why this is needed.
> ```

For example:

```
git range-diff --creation-factor=99 11f75961...1c1e98db
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually had to set it beyond hundred to work in my case ;)