# Why is "git format-patch" between two commits different from "git diff"?

Tags: git

Suppose there are 2 branches x1 and x2 both based on master. `git diff x1..x2` shows the diff between x1 and x2, but `git format-patch x1..x2 -1 --stdout` shows the diff between master and x2. Is there a way to let `format-patch` to show the diff between x1 and x2?

For example:

```
git branch x1 master
git branch x2 master
git switch x1
echo a >> README
git commit -a -m x1 # one extra line at x1
git switch x2
echo a >> README
echo a >> README
git commit -a -m x2 # 2 extra lines at x2

git diff x1..x2 # show one line betwen x1 and x2
git format-patch -1 --stdout x1..x2 # show 2 lines between master and x2
```

If I understand correctly, it seems `git format-patch` only emits real commits (could be stashed) but it will not try to calculate interdiff.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is “git format-patch” between two commits different from “git diff”?

The interpretation of `..` is different for the two commands. `git diff` is looking for two commits, `git format-patch` is looking for one or more patch series.

They're both trying to be helpful, to turn what you told them into something they can work with.

`git diff` effectively ignores the two dots. It's looking for two commits, you gave it two commits, those are the two commits. This is perhaps less baffling when you consider that it also has its own (quite useful, and sensible) interpretation of the three-dot syntax.

`git format-patch` is looking for patch series, so it uses the more common dots interpretation shared among all `git rev-list`-driven commmands.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: if you're looking for something like an interdiff, consider [git range-diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323008/can-somebody-explain-the-usage-of-git-range-diff).

#### Long

> If I understand correctly, it seems git format-patch only emits real commits (could be stashed) but it will not try to calculate interdiff.

This is correct, but may be coming from some wrong assumptions.

In particular, `git format-patch` is a method of turning a commit—or a whole chain of commits—into something that will survive email.  Whoever gets the patch can use `git am` to create an equivalent commit, preserving most of the metadata and the [`git patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id).<sup>1</sup>

Since this is aimed at preserving a *chain* of commits, format-patch looks specifically at a single chain of commits.  The `x1..x2` syntax you used is allowed, but when giving it a single revision, that's treated as a *since* specifier—that is, `git format-patch X` means `git format-patch X..HEAD`.

Note that in this kind of revision range—`A..B` for any valid specifiers `A` and `B`; see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more detail—commit `B` acts as a positive reference and is normally included in the selected commits, but `A` is a negative reference, as in `^A`, and is always excluded.  Hence if `A` and `B` name the same commit, `B` winds up being excluded too.  However, you can exclude a commit that normally wouldn't appear anyway.  In particular, you have created this situation:

```
       I   <-- x1
      /
...--H   <-- master
      \
       J   <-- x2
```

such that the commits selected by `x1..x2` are always just commit `J`, and the commits selected by `x2..x1` are always just commit `I`—the *same* set you'd get with `master..x2` and `master..x1` respectively.

(Note: the `-number` option to `git format-patch` forces a change in behavior when given a single commit specifier, instead of a range.  It doesn't seem to have any effect when using a range specifier.)

The `git diff` command, however, does not obey these rules.  Normally, a range `A..B` means *all commits reachable from `B`, excluding all commits reachable from `A`*, which is what we saw above with the `master`/`x1`/`x2` fork.  But `git diff A..B` just means `git diff A B`.  Git simply extracts commit `A` to use as the left side, and extracts commit `B` to use as the right side, and compares them.  There is no interdiff here either, nor any attempt to reach back to the common commit on `master`.

The `git diff` command has a special interpretation for the *three*-dot range syntax too: `git diff A...B` means *find a merge base between `A` and `B`, then compare that to commit `B`*.  This is also not any kind of interdiff—`git diff` just doesn't do that at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>The committer and committer-date are, by default, new when using `git am`.  However, you can also add `--committer-date-is-author-date`.  If you do this *and* you set things up so that your committer *name* matches the original committer name, and apply it to the right starting commit, you'll even get a commit that has the same hash ID, provided the original commit has the same author and committer dates.  That is, with a little effort, sometimes an emailed patch can result in a bit-for-bit identical commit, as if you had used [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the informational explanation. In fact, I was trying to find a diff output that I can directly `git am` without calling `git commit`. Now I think I can simply cat the header of `git format-patch` and the content of `git diff`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another scenario where `git format-patch` is actually using `git diff` with *more* than two commits, as explained in [this 2018 thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20180722095717.17912-1-sunshine@sunshineco.com/):

> When re-submitting a patch series, it is often helpful (for reviewers) to include an **interdiff** or **range-diff** against the previous version.
>
> Doing so requires manually running `git-diff` or `git-range-diff` and copy/pasting the result into the cover letter of the new version.
>
> This series automates the process by introducing `git-format-patch` options `--interdiff` and `--range-diff` which insert such a diff into the cover-letter or into the commentary section of the lone patch of a
> 1-patch series.
> In the latter case, the interdiff or range-diff is indented to avoid confusing git-am and human readers.

And, in another [2018 thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqva93t4u7.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/):

> When submitting a revised a patch series, the `--range-diff` option embeds
> a range-diff in the cover letter showing changes since the previous
> version of the patch series.
> The argument to `--range-diff` is a simple
> revision naming the tip of the previous series, which works fine if the
> previous and current versions of the patch series share a common base.
>
> However, it fails if the revision ranges of the old and new versions of
> the series are disjoint.
> To address this shortcoming, extend
> `--range-diff` to also accept an explicit revision range for the previous series.
> For example:
>
> ```
> git format-patch --cover-letter --range-diff=v1~3..v1 -3 v2
> ```

This is fixed with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), where "`format-patch --range-diff=<prev> <origin>..HEAD`" has been taught *not* to ignore `<origin>` when `<prev>` is a single version.

See [commit 07a7f8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07a7f8debfa43bd28537f475925776a92c30a678), [commit 72a7239](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72a7239016fa4c8919a8b6932ad76e5f820389eb), [commit cdffbdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdffbdc217aba8a39d786a642d1376a5a605adec) (08 Sep 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 634e008](https://github.com/git/git/commit/634e0084fac75cf85449a813da14968c9663a094), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07a7f8debfa43bd28537f475925776a92c30a678): use '`origin`' as start of current-series-range when known
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> When formatting a patch series over `origin..HEAD`, one would expect that range to be used as the current-series-range when computing a range-diff between the previous and current versions of a patch series.
>
> However, `infer_range_diff_ranges()` ignores `origin..HEAD` when `--range-diff=<prev>` specifies a single revision rather than a range, and instead unexpectedly computes the current-series-range based upon `<prev>`.
> Address this anomaly by unconditionally using `origin..HEAD` as the current-series-range regardless of `<prev>` as long as `origin` is known, and only fall back to basing current-series-range on `<prev>` when `origin` is not known.

---

Note that with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), the default option is clarified.

See [commit f024913](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f024913164ae6ec53bd97c0fb8481abb0fecd86d) (02 Apr 2023) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9e0d1aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e0d1aa495bd26f4688b915ac5c3cb656c9f7174), 21 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f024913164ae6ec53bd97c0fb8481abb0fecd86d): correct documentation of --thread without an argument
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Henrie</sup>

> In Git, almost all command line flags unconditionally override the corresponding config option (see [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAMMLpeS3+NUQa2oqpHKVo3yWQNVMgkEXrs4U5_ggvk31yQbezQ@mail.gmail.com/)).
>
> Add a test to confirm that this is the case for [`git format-patch --thread`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f024913164ae6ec53bd97c0fb8481abb0fecd86d/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L162)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt---threadltstylegt))</sup>.

`git format-patch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f024913164ae6ec53bd97c0fb8481abb0fecd86d/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L176):

> `--thread` without an argument is equivalent to `--thread=shallow`.

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), when "[`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b04671b638745ecdad70d3f22e9f5032f41fc26d/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> that uses the validate hook is fed a message without and then with Message-ID, it failed to auto-assign a unique Message-ID to the former and instead reused the Message-ID from the latter, which has been corrected.
This was a fix for a recent regression caught before the release, so no need to mention it in the release notes.

See [commit 20bd08a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20bd08aefb20168c6c227d2bfd1965761f9201ea), [commit 3ece9bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ece9bf0f9e24909b090cf348d89e8920bd4f82f) (17 May 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b04671b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b04671b638745ecdad70d3f22e9f5032f41fc26d), 19 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ece9bf0f9e24909b090cf348d89e8920bd4f82f): clear the `$message_id` after validation
>
> <sup>Tested-by: Douglas Anderson</sup>

> Recently [`git-send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3ece9bf0f9e24909b090cf348d89e8920bd4f82f/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> started parsing the same message twice, once to validate *all* the message before sending even the first one, and then after the validation hook is happy and each message gets sent, to read the contents to find out where to send to etc.
>
> Unfortunately, the effect of reading the messages for validation lingered even after the validation is done.
> Namely `$message_id` gets assigned if exists in the input files but the variable is global, and it is not cleared before `pre_process_file` runs.
> This causes reading a message without a `message-id` followed by reading a message with a `message-id t`o misbehave---the sub reports as if the message had the same id as the previously written one.
>
> Clear the variable before starting to read the headers in `pre_process_file`.

You can see in the [test for extracting patches](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ece9bf0f9e24909b090cf348d89e8920bd4f82f#diff-16ce3b881e9f20091758c36db652148b4430ad7929bc33fb7039641b96c77b86R50):

```
threaded_patches=$(git format-patch -o threaded --thread=shallow -s --in-reply-to="format" HEAD^1)
```

Comment: See also Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) and a leak fix: [commit c6d26a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6d26a9dda59043f95ee5bf632d6aa80fa50aad7), [commit cfa1209](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfa120947e6337e7be2658f71a0132e337ee090a) (18 May 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).  
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e490bea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e490bea8a68fceb227277fef38daa1b7522b97a5), 13 Jun 2023)</sup>