# Why `git range-diff` does not respect -w -b options?

Tags: git, git-range-diff

When `git` displays diff, there are implemented -w -b options in many places which ignores space changes. But occasionally `git diff-range` does not implement them. Why?

It would be useful to hide space changes in many cases (as for usual diff). For example:

[image]

Here these lines makes useless noise =(

```perl
$c->user->update({
  lastseen       => \'now()',
  seen_from_ip   => $ip,
  seen_from_city => $city,
});
```

Comment: What version of Git are you using? `git range-diff` has evolved quite a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229704/6309

Comment: @VonC: git version 2.21

Comment: Can you check with 2.27 (or 2.28 which should be released today)?