# Is it possible to Git diff 2 commits and only see the diff of the files that were changed in those commit?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a branch where I cherry-picked a commit `fd678b2` from Master for an another branch (branch-y). I had to make changes to that commit since `branch-y` is an old version branch and not everything was compatible and there were a lot of merge conflicts. After my changes I pushed the branch with a commit `2cbd583`.

So is there a way to see the difference between those 2 commits and where I only see the diff of files that were involved in those commit and not the whole branch.

I tried
`git diff fd678b2..2cbd583` but that shows me the diff of whole branch and doing the path way `git diff fd678b2..2cbd583 --path`is completely impractical since the commit is very big and checking individual file by adding path would take a very long time.

Comment: [`git range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) might be helpful – Stackoverflow explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323008/can-somebody-explain-the-usage-of-git-range-diff

Answer (score 0):

Try if this could be enough for you:

```
git diff --stat fd678b2..2cbd583 <THE_PATH>
```

Look at the file you want to inspect, then:

```
git diff fd678b2..2cbd583 <THE_FILE>
```

Comment: Using 'git diff --stat fd678b2..2cbd583 <THE_PATH>' again poses the same issue as I would have to add the file path individually. Normally it wouldn't be an issue but due to the commit being really big (a lot of files + path), this option becomes impractical. What I was hoping for was if there is a way to see the diff between both commits where only the files involved are shown.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
git diff --name-only fd678b2..2cbd583
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Hi, this again only shows every file in the branch and I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to see the diff between those files that were changed in the commit